Apple Health allows "sharing" of user HealthKit data. How can a "sharing" participant's data be queried?
Is the rumor true, that "hkParticipantQuery" is coming to the HealthKit Framework?
It doesn't appear to be supported in the September 16, 2024 Xcode 15.0 production release.
it doesn't appear to be supported in any of the Xcode 15.1 beta releases either...

Sharing users data is not available via HealthKit APIs. Would love to know your use case for it. File a feedback with details at feedback.apple.com

For many people (especially grandparent care), HealthCare is a"family project"...  We have an app that helps coordinate Family care, and having access to Apple Health "shared" biometrics would be very helpful.  We know this type of API is not available now, but rumours indicate it is coming to HealthKit.   Anybody have new news?
